# Exception of type 'uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttClientException' was thrown

Tags: c#, mqtt

I am connecting to the **mqtt** and I am receiving an un-helpful exception.

**Code**

```
string smsTopic = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQTT_SMS_Topic"];
string emailTopic = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQTT_Email_Topic"];
string pushTopic = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQTT_PUSH_Topic"];
string socialTopic = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MQTT_SOCIAL_Topic"];

client = new MqttClient("somehostname");
string clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
client.Connect(clientId);
client.MqttMsgPublishReceived += client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;
client.Subscribe(new string[] { smsTopic, emailTopic, pushTopic, socialTopic }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
```

**Exception Message**

> Exception of type 'uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttClientException' was thrown

**Stacktrace of the exception**

```
at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Messages.MqttMsgSubscribe.GetBytes(Byte protocolVersion) in c:\Users\ppatierno\Source\Repos\m2mqtt\M2Mqtt\Messages\MqttMsgSubscribe.cs:line 187
at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Send(MqttMsgBase msg) in c:\Users\ppatierno\Source\Repos\m2mqtt\M2Mqtt\MqttClient.cs:line 1028
at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.ProcessInflightThread() in c:\Users\ppatierno\Source\Repos\m2mqtt\M2Mqtt\MqttClient.cs:line 1954
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I founded a [bug on the github](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.m2mqtt/issues/5), but without solution

The exception Message is not helpful at all, and there is NO inner exception inside it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to solve this wired exception by changing the following statement

```
client.Subscribe(new string[] { smsTopic, emailTopic, pushTopic, socialTopic }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
```

to

```
client.Subscribe(new string[] { smsTopic }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
client.Subscribe(new string[] { emailTopic }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
client.Subscribe(new string[] { pushTopic }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
client.Subscribe(new string[] { socialTopic }, new byte[] { MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE });
```

it appears the `mqtt` has bug when specify more than one topic at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

Much better:

```
client.Subscribe(new string[] 
    { smsTopic, emailTopic, pushTopic, socialTopic }, 
    new byte[] { 
         MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, 
         MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE,
         MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE,
         MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE 
    }
);
```